# Why are the setAlignment methods on layouts static?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I noticed that the `setAlignment` method for layouts within JavaFX is static. Why is this the case? Doesn't this mean that a single node contained within two layouts of the same class cannot have two different alignments?

For example, I have a node called `introText` that I want to align differently within two different `BorderPane` objects:

```
BorderPane rootLayout = new BorderPane();
BorderPane infoLayout = new BorderPane();
Label introText = new Label("Select an Item");
rootLayout.setCenter(introText);
infoLayout.setTop(introText);
BorderPane.setAlignment(introText, Pos.CENTER);
#Now introText is positioned in the centre on both rootLayout and infoLayout.
```

How can I position `introText` as `Pos.TOP_LEFT` within `infoLayout` and `Pos.CENTER` within `rootLayout`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you can't actually run into the problem you describe. A `Node` can only appear once in the scene graph. If you add the same node to another parent without removing it from its current parent, then it will be silently removed from its current parent first. So, the answer to:

> How can I position `introText` as `Pos.TOP_LEFT` within `infoLayout` and `Pos.CENTER` within `rootLayout`?

Is: You can't, because `introText` cannot be a child of both `infoLayout` and `rootLayout` at the same time. Now, it may be that the properties of both `BorderPane` will contain the label, but that label will only be in **one** of their *children* lists, and only nodes in the children list will be rendered by that parent.

As for why methods like `BorderPane#setAlignment(Node,Pos)` are static, that's most likely because:

1. A `BorderPane` does not have a global alignment (unlike e.g., `HBox`), so it doesn't make sense to have an instance `alignment` property defined for it.
2. However, a `BorderPane` can end up with empty space in each of its "sections", and so it makes sense to allow the developer to define the alignment of each individual child `Node` to determine how they get positioned in that empty space.
3. But it doesn't make sense for `Node` to have an instance `alignment` property either. It's too specific a property for such a widely scoped class.
4. So, they defined a static `setAlignment` method on `BorderPane` which takes the `Node` to set the alignment for. This keeps the property scoped to the `BorderPane`, which is the class that makes uses of it, and associates the value with the `Node` instance, not the class.
5. And they made the method static because an instance method would imply the alignment state is stored with the `BorderPane` instance. That's not the case--the alignment state is stored with the given `Node` instance (see below).

These methods work by modifying the [properties map](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/19/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/Node.html#getProperties()) that each `Node` has. For instance, here's [the implementation](https://github.com/openjdk/jfx/blob/master/modules/javafx.graphics/src/main/java/javafx/scene/layout/BorderPane.java#L163) of `BorderPane#setAlignment(Node,Pos)`:

> ```
> public static void setAlignment(Node child, Pos value) {
>     setConstraint(child, ALIGNMENT, value);
> }
> ```

Which calls [this method](https://github.com/openjdk/jfx/blob/9768b5e42391e2d48aefffa3a3f6b1de6c30ef9d/modules/javafx.graphics/src/main/java/javafx/scene/layout/Pane.java#L107):

> ```
> static void setConstraint(Node node, Object key, Object value) {
>     if (value == null) {
>         node.getProperties().remove(key);
>     } else {
>         node.getProperties().put(key, value);
>     }
>     if (node.getParent() != null) {
>         node.getParent().requestLayout();
>     }
> }
> ```

So, as you can see, although these methods may be static, the state is still associated with a node *instance*. And yes, if you were to take the node out of one `BorderPane` and add it to another, then it would still have the same alignment. You'd have to change the alignment if and as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Similarly with `AnchorPane.setBootomAnchor`.
These methods modify `properties`. Otherwise, each control would have to implement the `setAlignment()` or `setBottomAnchor` methods.